# Close established TCP connection on Linux

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I am not able to find an answer to a simple thing I will try to achive:
once a tcp connection is established to my linux server, let's say ssh / tcp 22 or x11 / tcp 6000 display -> how do I close this connection **without** killing the process (sshd / x11 display server).
I saw also some suggestoin to use iptables, but it does not work for me, the connection is still visible in netstat -an.
would be good if someone can point me to the right direction.

what I tried so far

```
tcpkill: kills the process, not good for me
iptables: does not close the established connection, but prevent further connections.
```

Thanks in adavnce
DJ

Comment: Attach to the process with a debugger, then call `shutdown()` followed by `close()`, or just `close()`, on the appropriate file descriptor.  Then hope the process can handle that.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I found at least one solution (killcx) which is working. Maybe we will be able to find an easier solution. 
Also, i saw the comment from "zb" - thanks - which might also work, but I was not able to find a working syntax, since this tool seems to be really useful but complex. 
So here is an example how to work with the 1. solution which is working for me:

```
netstat -anp  | grep 22   
output: tcp  0  0 192.168.0.82:22         192.168.0.77:33597      VERBUNDEN   25258/0
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -s 192.168.0.77 (to prevent reconnect)
perl killcx.pl 192.168.0.77:33597 (to kill the tcp connection)
```

killcx can be found here: http://killcx.sourceforge.net/
it "steals" the connection from the foreign host (192.168.0.77) and close it. So that solution is working fine, but to complex to setup quickly if you are under stress. Here are the required packages:

```
apt-get install libnetpacket-perl  libnet-pcap-perl libnet-rawip-perl
wget http://killcx.sourceforge.net/killcx.txt -O killcx.pl
```

however, would be good to have an easier solution.

Answer (score 2):

tcpkill wont work, since it will only kill any new connection, it doesnt kill existing ESTABLISHED connections

heres how you remove an Established TCP connection

1. find the PID of the process and the IP of the client connecting,
   lets say you are on serverA and someone is connecting from serverB

   root@A> netstat -tulpan | grep ssh | grep serverB

should see something like,

```
tcp        0      0 <serverA IP>:<port>     <serverB>:<port>   ESTABLISHED 221955/sshd
```

2. use lsof utility to get the File Descriptor of this connection using the parent PID

   root@A> lsof -np 221995 | grep serverB IP

should see something like this

```
sshd 221955 <user>  17u IPv4 2857516568  0t0  TCP <serverA IP>:<port>-><serverB IP>:<port> (ESTABLISHED)
```

get the File Descriptor number (4th column) = 17u

3. use GDB to shut down this connection, w/out killing sshd

   root@A> gdb -p 211955 --batch -ex 'call shutdown(17u, 2)'

should see something similar,

```
0x00007f0b138c0b40 in __read_nocancel () from /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
$1 = 0
[Inferior 1 (process 211955) detached]
```

that TCP connection should now be closed

Comment: As alternative, it is possible to use `ss` instead of `netstat`:
`ss -tp '( sport = :22 )'`

Answer (score 0):

using `ss` to check an terminate them

> -K, --kill          forcibly close sockets, display what was closed

```bash
### list them
ss -tp '( sport = :443  )'

### or 
ss --tcp src :443

### terminate them
ss -K -tp '( sport = :443  )'

### or
ss --kill --tcp src :443
```

note: the first time `ss -K` is run , it kills and displays result, second time is run shows headers , no output; thus it appears that we have to run it twice but it is not the case, the first time it does

Tested on Debian 11

More [How to terminate dead connections from the command line without restarting server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71940/how-to-terminate-dead-connections-from-the-command-line-without-restarting-serve)